# Writing to disk gets slower over time with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, disk, file-writing

I am trying to write large files (500 MByte) to disk using Node.js. I figured out that while the first few files are being written in a few seconds (typically, 3 to 5 seconds), starting with around the 10th file things tend to get slower (and it won't recover).

The setup consists of a server that accepts files via a TCP/IP socket and pipes them to disk:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    net = require('net'),
    path = require('path');

var counter = 0;

net.createServer(function (socket) {
  console.time('received');
  console.time('written');

  counter++;

  var filename = path.join(__dirname, 'temp' + counter + '.tmp');
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename, { encoding: 'utf8' });

  socket.pipe(file);

  socket.once('end', function () {
    console.timeEnd('written');
  });

  file.once('finish', function () {
    console.timeEnd('received');
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

I send the data from the terminal using `nc` in the following way:

```
$ while [ true ]; do `cat input.tmp | nc localhost 3000`; done
```

Running

```
$ time cat input.tmp > /dev/null
```

has shown that cat reads the files in always the same time. If I replace the output path of the Node.js script to `/dev/null` the writing, too, always happens in the same time.

So the problem apparently is related to actually writing to disk.

I first thought that it *may* be a problem with concurrent reads and writes, but the problem even persists when I run

```
$ while [ true ]; do `cat input.tmp | nc localhost 3000; sleep 5`; done
```

If I run the same test with an even larger file (twice as large, i.e. 1 GByte) then it takes around half the time until the writing gets slower.

**UPDATE**

I've changed my Node.js application to write everything to a *single* file, which gets appended on and on and on… the server now looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    net = require('net'),
    path = require('path');

var filename = path.join(__dirname, 'temp.tmp');
var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename, { encoding: 'utf8' });

net.createServer(function (socket) {
  console.time('received');
  console.time('written');

  socket.pipe(file, { end: false });

  socket.once('end', function () {
    console.timeEnd('written');
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

Now the problem is gone, so apparently it has to do with writing multiple files in a row. At least *I* can't see where I am writing multiple files at the same time (am I?), so I can not think of a reason why this should happen. Especially the usage of `sleep 5` should make sure that the OS has really written everything to disk.

**UPDATE 2**

I originally tested using Node.js 0.10.32. As soon as I switch to 0.11.13, the effect is not gone completely, but it takes *way* more time until it happens. In the original setup, the problem arose at around 10 cycles, with Node.js 0.11.13 it happens earliest on cycle 30.

Any idea what might cause this behavior?

Comment: could you test it without node.js? There is a great chance you'll observe the same pattern. OS's construct castles to abstract the pain of HDD I/O, there are many factors involved, and let's just make sure it actually is Node.js, not OS, caching or anything. P.S. Some examples how to replace Node with NC here: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/06/netcat-a-couple-of-useful-examples/

Comment: Are you 100% sure you aren't leaking resources?  And, all file handles are being closed?

Comment: @jfriend00 If the handles were left open, it would just stop writing files altogether once the OS has no slots left, no?

Comment: Leaks of some types can cause excess memory consumption leading to swapping or memory thrashing of some kind.  I mentioned file handles because it wasn't completely apparent to me how everything got closed properly in the node.js example.

Comment: I had the same thought, but OP seems to catch the 'finish' event so I guess that part is OK

Comment: I'm *quite* sure that there are no leaking resources, but I would not *guarantee* it. In other words: There may be leaking things, but at least I don't see any apparent places where this could happen. `pipe` should clean up nicely, and for anything else I'm using `once`.

Comment: Regarding `nc`, basically I've tried it, but it only worked with one single file for all requests or with restarting `nc`, which is both not directly comparable to what I do with Node.js. For details see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356646/use-nc-to-write-multiple-files-how

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar issue a while back. There is a maximum of concurrent I/O operations possible so Node will start writing as many files at the same time as it can, and the rest will be queued until a slot is free.

```
file 1 |-----------------------------------|
file 2  |-----------------------------------|
file 3   |-----------------------------------|
file 4                                      |-------------------------------------|
```

The above is just an example but it shows the principle, writing 4 files in this case will take twice as long than writing only 3 files.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not too sure whether this helps, as I am sending the input files sequentially, not parallel. Or am I missing something in the way my test setup has been built?

Comment: Not sure either ;) One thing I'm pretty confident about is that it is most probably not a Node.js issue, your code seems fine to me. Have you tried using netcat like suggested in the comments to validate the 'OS issue' theory?

Comment: Yes, I did. Didn't shed any additional light to this, unfortunately :-(

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6118) apparently before 0.11 some kind of bug kept writable streams 'linger' after the finish event, that may or may not be related.