# Use nc to write multiple files - how?

Tags: bash, netcat

I want to use `nc` as a simple TCP/IP server. So far I run it using:

```
$ nc -k -l 3000 > temp.tmp
```

This works, but writes all the received data of all connections into one single file. But, I would like to have individual files.

Basically I get this if I skip the `-k` switch, but then `nc` shuts down as soon as the first connection is gone.

How can I keep `nc` running, but use an individual file for each incoming request? (Or, if this is not possible, is there an alternative *nix tool that is able to do this?)

Please note that I do *not* want to restart `nc`, but I want it all with a single running instance.

PS: I know that SO doesn't allow questions on finding tools, but for me this is only the fallback in case `nc` isn't able to do that by itself. So, sorry for the part in parentheses…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the receiver:

```
$ nc -p 3000 -l | tar -x
```

On the sender:

```
$ tar -c * | nc <ip_address> 3000
```

Comment: So simple yet elegant!

Comment: cool, but where do the files go lol? how do write them to a certain location?

Comment: @AlexanderMills This is more about how tar works than how nc works.   If you specify a relative path on the sender, the files go into the current working directory on the receiver.  To put them in a specific place: `nc -p 3000 -l | tar -x /the/folder/you/want`

Note that tar is an archive utility; if the sender specifies an absolute path, then the receiver will expand that into an absolute path and put the files there.  You can override this with tar option `--one-top-level`.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `-k` and run it in a loop:

```
n=0
while nc -l 3000 > "$n".txt ; do
   n=$((n+1))
done
```

Comment: Basically, this works perfectly, but I want to do it without restarting `nc`. (Sorry, I forgot to put that into my question, I'm going to add it now).

Comment: Ok, understood. I'm not sure if this is possible. Can have a closer look later.

Comment: @Golo Roden. What kind of OS are you using?

Comment: OS X and Ubuntu, but primarily OS X.

Comment: @GoloRoden Then it is likely that you are using the BSD version of netcat. There is also a version available which is called `netcat-traditional` (try on Ubuntu, its in the repos), it supports the `-e` options which can be used to start a script on every connect. You may have a look at that version of `nc`. Otherwise there might be a solution using `socat`, need to investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Cronolog](http://cronolog.org/usage.html) can help in this case

-p option you can determine the period option

Also the filewatcher utility "incron" can be used which will check logs to one file & can split to some other files

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, because the output is written to the individual files in parallel (so every file contains the very same data of all requests).

Comment: From question I thought you want parallel writing.
Then you should fallow log rotation approach