# netcat - receive multipart TCP/HTTP response with multiple files

Tags: http, tcp, multipartform-data, multipart, netcat

Using `netcat` or similar, how can I receive an HTTP response that contains multiple files (perhaps a multipart message)?

I need to save those files to disk. And as the client, in my case, I actually don't know how many files I will receive in advance.

I am looking for something like:

```
nc localhost 5000 | how can I read multiple files here and save each to disk?
```

I think this might be a possible answer: [Use nc to write multiple files - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356646/use-nc-to-write-multiple-files-how/44894223#44894223), since I am working with `.tgz` files.

Comment: It is unclear what *"or similar"* is for you. Also, what kind of response you get depends on what is implemented in the server, i.e. you cannot enforce multipart downloads if the server does not implement it (and most don't). Given that you don't specify what the server provides and how the appropriate request should look like I recommend to close the question as too broad.

Comment: well it's my server and I can implement multipart responses if I want to - if that's possible with http or tcp

Comment: I guess I am looking for conceptually how to send and how to receive multiple files with one request - I simply don't really know how to do either. With a client request, we can upload with http multipart, but I am looking to download multiple files here and like I said, I don't know many files I will receive.

Comment: I think this might be a possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44894223/1223975

Comment: If this is your server and you have full control over it (which is information you should put into your question) then why not just serve a ZIP file or TAR file by the server, i.e. `echo -en "GET /foo.tar HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n" | nc server port | tar -xvf - `

Comment: Writing an HTTP client in Unix shell is generally a bad idea. [What actual problem are you solving?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: I am trying to save .tgz files that are being sent from a server - I think this is correct: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443632/connect-to-server-with-netcat-and-receive-multiple-files-with-one-request-conn

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443810/receive-multiple-files-from-pipe-and-write-to-different-destinations

You can save it with timestamp suffix in this manner:

```
nc localhost 3440 | tar -x -O > ores-$(date +%s.%N).tgz
```

It will produce files with names like this:

```
ores-1526341128.393345176.tar.gz 
ores-1526341129.366798510.tar.gz 
ores-1526341332.305878646.tar.gz 
ores-1526341332.545975256.tar.gz 
ores-1526341332.786026292.tar.gz
```